# Why does my BottomNavigationView is not showing up?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to add a BottomNavigationView in my project but don't show up when i run the project.

I'd like to put this on several activities, aswell as Toolbar so i created a class that initialize both of them and extends AppCompatActivity so that my activies using the Toolbar or the BottomNavigationView just have to extends this activity and call the method that initialize it (i don't know if this is the right method to use, if no please tell me). So this work with my Toolbar, but my BottomNavigationView isn't showing up.

This is my NavigationActivity i talked about :

```
public abstract class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private BottomNavigationView mNavigationView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    public void initNavigation(int navigationId) {
        mNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(navigationId);
        mNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_entrainements:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MenuEntrainementsActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_nutrition:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),NutritionActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_statistiques:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),StatistiquesActivity.class));
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void initToolbar(int toolbarId) {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(toolbarId);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back_black_18dp);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.btnHome :
                startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.btnProfil :
                startActivity(new Intent(this,ProfilActivity.class));
                return true;
            default :
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

and an exemple of how i'm using it in others activities :

```
initNavigation(R.id.navigation);
initToolbar(R.id.toolbar);
```

this is how i implement the BottomNavigationView in my XML files :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

if you need anything else just ask,
thanks for your help :)
(sorry if i made mistakes i'm not great in english)

Comment: When you create a new android studio app project you can select bottom navigation activity demo app. Once it runs there you can compare why it doesn't run in your project

Answer (score 0):

I Use this from outside of onCreate mothod.

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                Fragment fragment;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.btnHome :
                        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
                        return true;
                    case R.id.btnProfil :
                        startActivity(new Intent(this,ProfilActivity.class));
                        return true;
                    default :
                        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
                        return true;

                }
            }
        };
```